# keep only forward slashes and numbers with regex replace

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to use regex replace to change this:

```
/category/45/p-e--sportswear/47/shorts-skorts
```

into:

```
/45/47/
```

I can strip all but the numbers but i'm not sure how to keep the forward slashes while removing other non alphanumeric characters.

```
urlReferrer = Regex.Replace(urlReferrer, @"[^\d]", string.Empty);
```

Can someone help me with the correct pattern please?

Comment: why you won't want to get `//45//47/` as output? Use `[^\/\d]+` regex and replace all the matched characters with empty string. But it gives `//45//47/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
urlReferrer = Regex.Replace(urlReferrer, @"/[^/\d]+", string.Empty);
//=> /45/47
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bU1sR9/1)

Comment: The OP wanted the output to be `/45/47/`.  This is missing the trailing `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this instead of a regular expression:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
bool first = true;
bool lastNumeric = true;
bool atLeastOneNumeric = false;
foreach (var part in urlReferrer.Split('/'))
{
    if (part.Length > 0 && part.All(char.IsDigit))
    {
        if (!first)
            builder.Append("/");
        builder.Append(part);
        lastNumeric = true;
        atLeastOneNumeric = true;
    }
    else
    {
        lastNumeric = false;
    }

    first = false;
}

if (!lastNumeric && atLeastOneNumeric)
    builder.Append("/");

urlReferrer = builder.ToString();
```

This is braking the string by the '/' and then checking which tokens are numeric and appends them to the result.  Additionally it keeps track to see if the first token was numeric then there would not be a '/' before it, or if the last token is numeric then there would not be a '/' after it.  It also makes sure to not include any '/'s if there are no numeric values.

Here's a shorter version using `string.Join` and Linq

```
var tokens = urlReferrer.Split('/');

urlReferrer = string.Join("/", tokens.Where(s => s.Length > 0 && s.All(char.IsDigit)));

if(urlReferrer.Length > 0)
{
    if (tokens.First().Length == 0 || !tokens.First().All(char.IsDigit))
        urlReferrer = "/" + urlReferrer;

    if (tokens.Last().Length == 0 || !tokens.Last().All(char.IsDigit))
        urlReferrer += "/";
}
```

This simply splits the string by `/` then joins the numeric values together with `/` as the separator.  Then it checks to see if there were any numbers before checking if the first an last values where numeric or not to determine if a preceding and/or a following `/` is needed.